# Data must be 1-dimensional erro

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have following code in python in which I want to get id and it's probability

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc,roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


train_df=pd.read_csv('ML_EX4_train.csv')
test_df=pd.read_csv('ML_EX4_test.csv')
feature_names=['title_word_count','document_entropy','freshness','easiness','fraction_stopword_presence','normalization_rate',
                'speaker_speed','silent_period_rate']
test_df.index=test['id']
train_df.index=train['id']
X=train_df[feature_names]
y=train_df['engagement']
X_test=test_df[feature_names]
rf_clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0,max_depth= 20, min_samples_leaf= 1, n_estimators= 300).fit(X_train,y_train)
y_test_proba=rf_clf.predict_proba(X_test)
ans=pd.Series(y_test_proba,index=test_df['id'])

print(ans)
```

It should give answer in following way

| id |  |
| --- | --- |
| 9240 | 0.401958 |
| 9241 | 0.105928 |

However on running this code I am getting "ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional". can someone help me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is a binary classification problem.
[`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) returns the probabilities for all classes in multiple columns. If you want the probability for only one of the classes, you can select one column only by doing the following:

```py
y_test_proba=rf_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] # or [:,0] depending on the class you are interested in
ans=pd.Series(y_test_proba,index=test_df['id'])
```

In order to be consistent with the column you select, you can do this:

```py
class_to_predict = 1    # or 0 depending on the class you are interested in
column = np.where(rf_clf.classes_ == class_to_predict)[0][0]
y_test_proba=rf_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,column]
ans=pd.Series(y_test_proba,index=df.index)
```